# How can I gain a combat advantage with a bluff check?

Tags: dnd-4e

I've  read the following thing in wizards.com compendium:
"Once per encounter, a creature can try to gain combat advantage against a target by making a Bluff check."

So, I have two questions about it:

1. What action is this - standard, move, minor, free?
2. Is this roll being made against 10 or against creatures will?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wax Eagle pretty much has it, but *Create a Diversion to Hide* and *Gain Combat Advantage* through Bluff are 2 different things, although very similar.

Via *Rules Compendium* page 141

> ### Bluff
>
> **Gain Combat Advantage**
>   Make a Bluff check to gain combat advantage against an enemy by feining.
>
> **Action:** Standard action. A creature can take this action only once per encounter.
>
> **Opposed Check:** Against an adjacent target's passive Insight.
>
> **Success:** The feinting creature gains combat advantage against the target until the end of the feinting creature's next turn.

So yes you can also use *Create Diversion to Hide* to gain combat advantage as well, however that requires the success of 2 rolls as opposed to the 1 when using *Gain Combat Advantage*.

Comment: Also, unlike *Create a Diversion to Hide*, *Gain Combat Advantage* lasts until the end of the *next* turn.

Answer (score 2):

From [Bluff](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/skill.aspx?id=3):

> CREATE A DIVERSION TO HIDE
>
> Make a Bluff check to create a diversion and become hidden using the Stealth
>   skill.
>
> Action: Standard action. A creature can take this action only once per encounter.
>
> Opposed Check: Against a target’s passive Insight. The target must be able to see the creature creating the diversion. A creature can make the check against multiple targets at once, opposing the passive Insight of each target with a single Bluff check.
>
> Success: The creature can immediately make a Stealth check opposed by the passive Perception of any target that failed the opposed Bluff check. If the Stealth check succeeds against a target, the creature becomes hidden from that target until the end of the current turn or until immediately after the hidden creature makes an attack.

So to answer your questions, the action type is Standard *unless* otherwise specified (There are powers that let you do this as part of the action). And the DC is the passive insight of everyone who can see you creating the diversion. The *result* is that you can then make a stealth check to hide until the end of your turn.

This really only works if you're burning an action point or have a minor action attack, otherwise it's a waste of a turn.

Comment: Is "Create a diversion to hide" the same thing as gaining "combat challenge" with a bluff check?

Comment: @OleksandrGalichenko It's a way to gain combat advantage with a bluff check. But now that I read that, I think you may be quoting something else. Could you include the source of the quote in your question?

Comment: Unfortutely, I don't know how to provide you with the URL... This quote was from http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ , search "Combat Advantage" in "Glossary" section. Actually, I've found the answer in your URL, thanks :)

Comment: @OleksandrGalichenko depending on your browser, you can get a bare link to an article with either a right click "open in new tab" or by middle clicking the article